# Stuck installing Openstack with MAAS and Juju

Tags: cloud, openstack, ceph, juju, maas

I am trying to install Openstack using Juju and MaaS. I am following the following documentation: https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-openstack.html

But when I pass the command :

"juju deploy -n 4 --config ceph-osd.yaml --constraints tags=compute ceph-osd"

From what I understand my 4 Openstack nodes should get deployed together in MAAS. But once I pass that command, the 4 nodes switch between ready>allocated>deploying> ready..

I manage to get one deployed but the other 3 do not get deployed. I'm trying to figure out why.

Or if not, how do I pass that command separately for each node.

Answer (score 0):

please share `juju status` after deployed state.

for separate deployment use this command: `juju deploy --config ceph-osd.yaml --constraints tags=compute ceph-osd"`